# Saving file format after editing it with ConfigParser

Tags: python, edit, configparser

i am using ConfigParser to write some modification in a configuration file, basically what i am doing is :

- retrieve my urls from an api
- write them in my config file
  but after the edit, i noticed that the file format has changed :
  Before the edit :

```
[global_tags]

 [agent]
     interval = "10s"
     round_interval = true
     metric_batch_size = 10000
 [[inputs.cpu]]
     percpu = true
     totalcpu = true
 [[inputs.prometheus]]
   urls= []
   interval = "140s"
   [inputs.prometheus.tags]
     exp = "exp"
```

After the edit :

```
[global_tags]

[agent]
interval = "10s"
round_interval = true
metric_batch_size = 10000
[[inputs.cpu]
percpu = true
totalcpu = true
[[inputs.prometheus]
interval = "140s"
response_timeout = "120s"
[inputs.prometheus.tags]
exp = "snmp"
```

the offset changed and all the comments that were in the file has been deleted, my code :

```
edit = configparser.ConfigParser(strict=False, allow_no_value=True, empty_lines_in_values=False)
edit.read("file.conf")
edit.set("[section]", "urls", str(urls))
print(edit)

# Write changes back to file
with open('file.conf', 'w') as configfile:
    edit.write(configfile)
```

I have already tried : SafeConfigParser, RawConfigParser but it doesn't work.

when i do a print(edit.section()), here is what i get : ['global_tags', 'agent', '[inputs.cpu', , '[inputs.prometheus', 'inputs.prometheus.tags']
Is there any help please ?

Comment: The `configparser` module does not support pass-through of comments and formatting, so you'll probably need something else.

Comment: @AKX  do you know an alternatif of it, please ?

Comment: If the only thing you'd be doing is adding/modifying a single `urls`, it might be better to just roll your own "filter" that reads a config and returns (possibly) modified lines.

Comment: Also, the "ini" format does not support multiple nested sections. You could try the `YAML` format for the nested support, but even that won't preserve the exact same indentation when you save.

Comment: i am thinking of using after this another module that will do the desired indentation

Comment: Is the identation, in your case, an indication of hierarchy? Say, are `[global_tags]` and `[agent]` on the same hierarchical level and just happen to be indented weirdly, or is `[agent]` a nested child node of `[global_tags]`? If there is a nested hierarchy, then ini format probably won't cut it. Also, if another module is creating that indentation, can't you take a look at this other module to see how it is generating the configuration and why? This is a highly suspicious config format.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK Based on `global_tags` it's [probably a Telegraf TOML configuration](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/CONFIGURATION.md), so [`tomlkit`](https://github.com/sdispater/tomlkit) would do the trick.

Comment: @AKX makes perfect sense. It does look like [TOML](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml#toml)

Comment: yes it's a telegraf configuration file, i updated the format it in the question

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a "filter" parser that retains all other formatting but changes the `urls` line in the `agent` section if it comes across it:

```
import io


def filter_config(stream, item_filter):
    """
    Filter a "config" file stream.
    :param stream: Text stream to read from.
    :param item_filter: Filter function; takes a section and a line and returns a filtered line.
    :return: Yields (possibly) filtered lines.
    """
    current_section = None
    for line in stream:
        stripped_line = line.strip()
        if stripped_line.startswith('['):
            current_section = stripped_line.strip('[]')
        elif not stripped_line.startswith("#") and " = " in stripped_line:
            line = item_filter(current_section, line)
        yield line


def urls_filter(section, line):
    if section == "agent" and line.strip().startswith("urls = "):
        start, sep, end = line.partition(" = ")
        return start + sep + "hi there..."
    return line


# Could be a disk file, just using `io.StringIO()` for self-containedness here
config_file = io.StringIO("""
    [global_tags]

        [agent]
            interval = "10s"
            round_interval = true
            metric_batch_size = 10000
    # HELLO! THIS IS A COMMENT!
            metric_buffer_limit = 100000
            urls = ""

                [other]
                urls = can't touch this!!!
""")

for line in filter_config(config_file, urls_filter):
    print(line, end="")
```

The output is

```
    [global_tags]

        [agent]
            interval = "10s"
            round_interval = true
            metric_batch_size = 10000
    # HELLO! THIS IS A COMMENT!
            metric_buffer_limit = 100000
            urls = hi there...
                [other]
                urls = can't touch this!!!
```

so you can see all comments and (mis-)indentation was preserved.

Comment: That will work nicely, as long as @Sarahack does not intend the configuration to be hierarchical.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're passing brackets with the section name, which is unnecessary:

```py
edit.set("[section]", "urls", str(urls))
```

See this example from the documentation:

```py
import configparser

config = configparser.RawConfigParser()

# Please note that using RawConfigParser's set functions, you can assign
# non-string values to keys internally, but will receive an error when
# attempting to write to a file or when you get it in non-raw mode. Setting
# values using the mapping protocol or ConfigParser's set() does not allow
# such assignments to take place.
config.add_section('Section1')
config.set('Section1', 'an_int', '15')
config.set('Section1', 'a_bool', 'true')
config.set('Section1', 'a_float', '3.1415')
config.set('Section1', 'baz', 'fun')
config.set('Section1', 'bar', 'Python')
config.set('Section1', 'foo', '%(bar)s is %(baz)s!')

# Writing our configuration file to 'example.cfg'
with open('example.cfg', 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

But, anyway, it won't preserve the identation, nor will it support nested sections; you could try the `YAML` format, which does allow to use indentation to separate nested sections, but it won't keep the *exact* same indentation when saving, but, do you really need it to be the *exact* same? Anyway, there are various configuration formats out there, you should study them to see what fits your case better.

Comment: I'm quite sure using `RawConfigParser()` won't retain comments and indentation.

Comment: There's that detail, too